# Magento: Show a popup to a visitor after X no. of pages

Tags: php, mysql, magento, popup

I want to show a popup to a visitor once he's on the third page since his visit has started.

I found that the table `log_url` stores the visitor_id and url_id. I was thinking if we can count the number of url_id records for a certain visitor_id, that would let me show the popup once that visitor has crossed the count of 3.

What would be the best way to do this? Also, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @MageZeus comments, it seemed a much better option to just set a cookie when the visitor reaches the page and increment it to show the popup once the counter reached 4. Querying the database to get the pageviews for each unique visitor would've put an unnecessary load on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie or LocalStorage increments or Session with a IP identifier.

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setData('visits', array($ipAddress, 1));
```

Get the data now and increment it. After 4 visits reset the data.

HTH

Good luck

Comment: Hi MageZeus. I think you misunderstood my question. I wanted to count the number of pages that a visitor has gone through, not the number of visits.

Comment: I know. Just create an observer for the pageviews, save the visits with an if-statement > 4 = Popup. But anyway, if you have a lot visitors this would damage your server performance, because you have to cycle through the array for every pageview. I would just use JS for that kind of work. increment the pageviews with a cookie and fire up the popup after 4 views. Then save a "-1" in it to know the popup already has been fired.

Comment: You're probably right. The JS method seems to be the better option. Would you be able to guide me to some articles on how I can implement this? :)

Comment: Ok, correction. You are right! :) I was over complicating things in my head. I've set a cookie now when the visitor comes, incremented it by 1 for each page view and when the counter hit 4 I showed the popup. Didn't have to set it to -1 since the condition was that only when the counter hit 4, the popup would show. Since the cookie was set to expire in a day, the counter would reset itself the next day.